# How to make nginx redirect if none of the location blocks are matched?

Tags: nginx

I was hoping that this would work, but the final line acts even if one of the location blocks has been matched.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name a.mydomain.com;

    location /f/ {
        alias /var/www/sites/mydomain/photos/;
        expires 1y;
    }

    location /img/ {
        alias /var/www/sites/mydomain/http/img/;
        expires 1y;
    }

    location /css/ {
        alias /var/www/sites/mydomain/http/css/;
        expires 1y;
    }

    location /fonts/ {
        alias /var/www/sites/mydomain/http/fonts/;
        expires 1y;
    }


    return 301 http://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

How could I rewrite this to do what I want it to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the return in a `location /`

```
location / {
    return 301 http://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

`location /` is matched when no other location is matched.

Comment: So simple, and i remember reading it when I first set nginx up a couple of weeks ago now.  Thank you!